# fetch all youtube videos using curl

Tags: php, youtube

I'm a beginner at PHP.  I have one task in my project, which is to fetch all videos from a YouTube link using curl in PHP.  Is it possible to show all videos from YouTube?

I found this code with a Google search:

```
<?php
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.youtube.com');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $contents = curl_exec ($ch);
 echo $contents;
 curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

It shows the YouTube site, but when I click any video it will not play.

Comment: _All_ videos from youtube??? Wow. You'd better have a good connection.

Comment: ...and a couple datacenters' worth of hard drive space.

Comment: Jon can u help me i cannt  understand fetch videos from youtube

Comment: please be specific about what exactly you want?  i guess for sure you dont wanna host all youtube videos, but only their links right?

Comment: have you tried html <iframe> ?

Comment: no but client asked to do it in curl thats why..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get data from youtube oemebed interface in two formats `Xml` and `Json` which returns metadata about a video:

```
http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url={videoUrlHere}&format=json
```

Using your example, a call to:

```
http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4CRkpBGQzU&format=json
```

So, You can do like this:

```
$url = "Your_Youtube_video_link";
```

Example :

```
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7svJHmgJqs"

$youtube = "http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=" . $url. "&format=json";
$curl = curl_init($youtube);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$result = json_decode($return, true);
echo $result['html'];
```

Try it...Hope it will help you.

Comment: i tried your script but json_decode is returning null. Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

You could use curl to retrieve the Google main page (or an alternative page) and parse the returned html using a library such as [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/). If you wanted to try this approach the first step could be to 'view source' on the relevant page and look at how the links are structured.

A more elegant way to approach the problem could be to use the Youtube API (a way to interact with the Youtube system), which may allow you to retrieve the links directly. e.g it may be possible to just ask the Youtube API to send you the links. Try [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php?hl=nb#Retrieving_and_searching_for_videos).

Answer (score 1):

You can also get all youtube's channel videos using `file_get_contents`

bellow is sample and working code

```
<?php
$Youtube_API_Key = ""; // you can obtain api key :  https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application
$Youtube_channel_id = "";
$TotalVideso = 50; // 50 is max , if you want more video you need Youtube secret key.
$order= "date"; ////allowed order : date,rating,relevance,title,videocount,viewcount
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=".$Youtube_API_Key."&channelId=".$Youtube_channel_id."&part=id&order=".$order."&maxResults=".$TotalVideso."&format=json";
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$JsonDecodeData=json_decode($data, true);
print_r($data);
?>
```